# How to represent a sum of exponentials as one exponential

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, exponential-function, exponential-sum

Let us say, we have a sum of exponentials, such as:
$$
a (e^{iwt}+e^{-iwt})+b (e^{i2wt}-e^{-i2wt})+c (e^{i3wt}+e^{-i3wt}).
$$
Is there a way that represents the above sum as a sum of two exponentials with exponents that only differ in sign, i.e.,
$$
a (e^{iwt}+e^{-iwt})+b (e^{i2wt}-e^{-i2wt})+c (e^{i3wt}+e^{-i3wt})\stackrel{!}{=}A e^{ip(t)}+B e^{-ip(t)}\, ?
$$
I know, one can write the pairwise sums in terms of sin and cos, in that case the question would be, if one can find for any combination of oscillations a single trigonometric function that contains the combinations in its argument?

Comment: The range of $A \cos x + B \sin x$ is $I=[-\sqrt{A^2+B^2}, \sqrt{A^2+B^2}]$ and so by choosing $A,B$ large enough so that $I$ includes the range of the left hand side, you can always find $p(t)$ for which the equality holds.

Comment: @Marco That is a good point. So, the range of the left hand side would be $I=\left[ -\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}, \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2} \right]$, and now, $A$ and $B$ have to be chosen such that $\sqrt{A^2+B^2}>\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$?

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$a (e^{iwt}+e^{-iwt})+b (e^{i2wt}-e^{-i2wt})+c (e^{i3wt}+e^{-i3wt})=$$$$=2a \cos (wt)+2ib \sin (2wt)+2c \cos (3wt)=\ldots$$

then by trigonometric identities

- $\cos (3wt)=4\cos^3 (wt)-3\cos (wt)$
- $\sin (2wt)=2\cos (wt)\sin (wt)$

therefore

$$\ldots=2a \cos (wt)+4ib\cos (wt)\sin (wt)+8c\cos^3 (wt)-6c\cos (wt)=$$

$$=(2a-6c)\cos (wt)+8c\cos^3 (wt)+4ib\cos (wt)\sin (wt)=$$

$$=(a-3c)(e^{iwt}+e^{-iwt})+c(e^{iwt}+e^{-iwt})^3+b(e^{iwt}+e^{-iwt})(e^{iwt}-e^{-iwt})$$

that is an expression in term of $e^{iwt}$.

Comment: The middle term should be $2ib \sin(2wt)$

Comment: Thank you, but as pointed in the question, I know that one can write those exponentials in terms of sin and cos. It does not take anywhere though

Comment: @Mattos Opsss...thanks  lost the minus sign.

Comment: @mr.curious We can obtain a non-linear expression in term of $e^{iwt}$ thus it seems not possible to obtain  the desidered linear expression.

Comment: @gimusi Thank you very much. I think I did not formulate my question clearly enough. I want to write the expression in terms of a linear combination of sine or cosine with a new argument g(t), so no ()^2 or ()^3 terms or terms of sin()cos() are wished.